# turicreate image classifier for unknown types

Tags: python, ios, machine-learning, coreml, turi-create

I am using truicreate to create mlmodel for my iOS app. My aim is to classify different furnitures. it is working fine, but I want to identify the unknown type i.e. not included in my dataset. Is is possible to find that?

My Ref: https://www.appcoda.com/core-ml-model-with-python/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A classifier can only identify the things that are in your dataset.

It is possible to add an "unknown" category, but you'll have to add all kinds of different objects to this category (non-furniture objects and furniture that isn't in your main dataset).

Comment: Thanks for your valuable answer , I will check and let you know